# Why is Code First from MySQL Database not creating model, connectionString?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

So I have the following:

- VS2015 Enterprise 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
- MySQL for VisualStudio 1.2.4
- Connector/NET 6.9.7

Nuget:

- EntityFramework 6.1.3
- MySql.Data 6.9.7
- MySql.Data.Entities 6.8.3
- MySql.Web 6.9.7

And the following in Web.config:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Within Server Explorer I have a valid connection to a remote MySql Server instance and read/write tables, etc. However, when I try to add an ADO.NET entity and select 'Code first from database', hit next, select the connection, mark "Yes, include the sensitive data in the connection string" and leave the "Save connection settings Web.Config as:" checked as well as the name textfield and then hit next, Visual Studio seems to think a bit, shows the picture below real quick, and then the wizard closes. However, there are no models created nor is there a `connectionString` created in Web.config. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Does it happen with other database?

Comment: It works fine with a local Microsoft SQL Server database spun up in VS. I have read access to the database I'm have issues with and can use Server Explorer just fine to update row entries so I'm not sure if the issue is the MySql Nuget packages not working properly with EF or something. :(

Comment: Try to create another MySQL database, with just 1 table... just for testing

Comment: Created a local MySQL database and get same issue; can view/write in Server Explorer but Code First model creation exits out without any prompts after pressing next on the select connection, etc panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this problem and was never able to fix it, I think VS just can't manage the Mysql Database inside its server explorer for datasets/binding.

Even in WPF, I had to manually build Dataset objects for WPF binding - it was a pain in the arse. If you can, stick with MSSQL or learn how to program MySQL, in C#/VB.NET it's not nice.

Comment: Bounty given for giving additional testimony && commentary. It seems like several other people have had this issue since at least circa June 2015 (so it's been ongoing for ~3 months) given the filing of this MySQL for VIsual Studio bug. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77887

Answer (score 1):

Change your target platform from Any CPU / x64 to x86

Comment: Unfortunately changing the debug build to use x86 did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the MySQL VS tooling

Comment: That's what I figured given both remote and local instances of MySql are failing to do code first migration, but I have read/write access inside of Server Explorer, however given the volume of Nuget packages required I'm not sure if this issue lies on MS's side or Oracle's side...I presume Oracle, but I could be wrong...

Comment: Given that the EDM Wizard works  fine with SQL Server, SQL Server Compact and (sometimes) SQLite, I would say Oracle

Comment: I have struggled to get Code First working in VS 2015 with EF6 and MySQL all day. Incredibly frustrating. What is really bugging me is that ASP.NET Identity 2.0 works fine in my MVC 5 project against MySQL (after massive tweaking over several days to get edmx created. However, when I try to add a new dbcontext to get additional tables created it is an epic fail. After 20 years as a Microsoft Stack developer the issues never end...

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the existing connection string in web.config and start with the wizard.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have the same version on Connector/NET and MySql.Data.Entities.
Late answer, but still it is critical problem in using MySQL with ASP.Net.

Here the screenshots from the actual working project:

[image]

Comment: This has most likely been downvoted because if you have installed the Connector it installed the MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity DLL's so you should be using them and not the ones from NuGet.

Comment: It was downvoted because i don't have permission to place screenshots, still somehow need to place it properly into answer.

Nuget is more important because on remote build machine you don't have opportunity to install Connector, and add built DLL into project is bad practice.

Comment: yeah your right but then you should use NuGET and not the Connector you should not mix the two, use the DLL's from NuGET or do the what NuGET does and use the DLL's from the connector and set them to copy local so when it builds your application you will have `yourapp.exe, MySql.Data.Entity.dll ...` in the same directory.

Comment: Sorry,I just don't understand first point, thanks. Don't know that Connector handle packages too, i thought that it's just for VS inner instruments.